# Trapezoid Rule in Python

Tags: python, numerical-integration

I am trying to write a program using Python v. 2.7.5 that will compute the area under the curve y=sin(x) between x = 0 and x = pi. Perform this calculation varying the n divisions of the range of x between 1 and 10 inclusive and print the approximate value, the true value, and the percent error (in other words, increase the accuracy by increasing the number of trapezoids). Print all the values to three decimal places.

I am not sure what the code should look like. I was told that I should only have about 12 lines of code for these calculations to be done.

I am using Wing IDE.

This is what I have so far

```
# base_n = (b-a)/n
# h1 = a + ((n-1)/n)(b-a)
# h2 = a + (n/n)(b-a)
# Trap Area = (1/2)*base*(h1+h2)
# a = 0, b = pi

from math import pi, sin

def TrapArea(n):
for i in range(1, n):
    deltax = (pi-0)/n
    sum += (1.0/2.0)(((pi-0)/n)(sin((i-1)/n(pi-0))) + sin((i/n)(pi-0)))*deltax
    return sum

for i in range(1, 11):
    print TrapArea(i)
```

I am not sure if I am on the right track. I am getting an error that says "local variable 'sum' referenced before assignment. Any suggestions on how to improve my code?

Comment: You never defined `sum` anywhere. You're trying to do `sum = sum + (1.0/.....)`

Comment: `(1.0/2.0)(...)` won't multiply the two terms. It'll call the result of `1.0 / 2.0` with `...` as the first argument.

Comment: you can't multiply stuff in python like (x)(y).You have to use x*y.

Comment: Okay, now I changed sum += to just =, and now it's telling me 'int' object is not callable.

Comment: You can simplify that calculation to `sum += 0.5*((pi/n)(sin((i-1)/n*pi)) + sin((i/n)*pi))*deltax`. Also, define sum before the loop: `sum = 0`.

Comment: Alright, I did all of your suggestions, and my code is now giving me a list of a bunch of 0.0's, and it says "None"

Comment: How can it print "None"? Are you assigning to "sum" properly before you return it?

Answer (score 3):

Your original problem and problem with Shashank Gupta's answer was `/n` does integer division. You need to convert `n` to `float` first:

```
from math import pi, sin

def TrapArea(n):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(1, n):
        deltax = (pi-0)/n
        sum += (1.0/2.0)*(((pi-0)/float(n))*(sin((i-1)/float(n)*(pi-0))) + sin((i/float(n))*(pi-0)))*deltax
    return sum

for i in range(1, 11):
    print TrapArea(i)
```

Output:

```
0
0.785398163397
1.38175124526
1.47457409274
1.45836902046
1.42009115659
1.38070223089
1.34524797198
1.31450259385
1.28808354
```

---

Note that you can heavily simplify the `sum += ...` part.

First change all `(pi-0)` to `pi`:

```
sum += (1.0/2.0)*((pi/float(n))*(sin((i-1)/float(n)*pi)) + sin((i/float(n))*pi))*deltax
```

Then do `pi/n` wherever possible, which avoids needing to call `float` as `pi` is already a `float`:

```
sum += (1.0/2.0)*(pi/n * (sin((i-1) * pi/n)) + sin(i * pi/n))*deltax
```

Then change the `(1.0/2.0)` to `0.5` and remove some brackets:

```
sum += 0.5 * (pi/n * sin((i-1) * pi/n) + sin(i * pi/n)) * deltax
```

Much nicer, eh?

Comment: Oh okay! I see now. Thank you! I am still trying to get the whole "float" and "int" thing down.

Comment: Even nicer is to observe that pi/n doesn't change throughout the loop.  That leads to an optimization that cuts the number of sine computations in half.  I guess I should put code in an answer...

Comment: @MikeHousky Now my second question is to be able to compute the exact area value. What is written already is the approximation. For the exact area: I am defining a new function called ExactTrapArea, but my formatting is not working out correctly. My ultimate goal is to be able to compute the Exact area so that I can get the percentage error which requires the exact area and the approximate area.

Comment: This should be a new question.

Comment: @user2763502 You can't get an exact area from the trapezoid rule, in general, and in this case you have downward concavity except for inflection points at the endpoints.  No matter how many intervals you pick, every one will have a small positive sliver of area between the trapezoid and sine curve that isn't counted.  The best you can do is get the number of intervals up to where the error is less than one least significant bit in the float.  Look at the numbers in my answer and you'll see that it will take a lot of intervals.

Answer (score 1):

You have some indentation issues with your code but that could just be because of copy paste. Anyways adding a line `sum = 0` at the beginning of your `TrapArea` function should solve your current error. But as @Blender pointed out in the comments, you have another issue, which is the lack of a multiplication operator (`*`) after your floating point division expression `(1.0/2.0)`.

Remember that in Python expressions are not always evaluated as you would expect mathematically. Thus `(a op b)(c)` will not automatically multiply the result of `a op b` by `c` like you would expect with a mathematical expression. Instead this is the function call notation in Python.

Also remember that you must initialize all variables before using their values for assignment. Python has no default value for unnamed variables so when you reference the value of `sum` with `sum += expr` which is equivalent to `sum = sum + expr` you are trying to reference a name (`sum`) that is not binded to any object at all.

The following revision to your function should do the trick. Notice how I place multiplication operators (`*`) between every expression that you intend to multiply.

```
def TrapArea(n):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(1, n):
        i = float(i)
        deltax = (pi-0)/n
        sum += (1.0/2.0)*(((pi-0)/n)*(sin((i-1)/n*(pi-0))) + sin((i/n)*(pi-0)))*deltax
    return sum
```

EDIT: I also dealt with the float division issue by converting `i` to `float(i)` within every iteration of the loop. In Python 2.x, if you divide one integer type object with another integer type object, the expression evaluates to an integer regardless of the actual value.

Comment: Okay, I revised it, but now my code after it runs is printing a bunch of 0.0's

Comment: There was another problem where you were returning `sum` from within your loop instead of after the loop. @Veedrac fixed it for me in his edit.

Comment: What do you mean by 0.0's?

Comment: I really appreciate the help, I have very basic knowledge of python. My code is still printing a list of 0.0's.

Comment: @user2763502 That means your TrapArea function is returning 0.0 every time regardless of the argument you send to it. Perhaps your formula is incorrect?

Comment: Hmm, well I know that the nth base of a trapezoid has the formula: (b-a)/n. I know that h1 of a trapezoid is: a + ((n-1)/n)(b-a). I know that h2 of a trapezoid is: a + (n/n)(b-a). These are generalized. The trap area = (1/2)*base*(h1+h2).

Comment: The OP is using Python 2, so he's being bitten by integer division.  `i` and `n` are both ints, so `(i-1)/n` and `(i/n)` are both 0, and `sin(0) == 0`.  [PS: `sum` is a bad variable name because that shadows the builtin.]

Comment: @DSM Thanks, I integrated your suggestion into my answer by convering `i` to `float(i)` at the beginning of the loop.

Comment: Okay, so I know that the code that is printing is the approximate value. How do I implement code that prints the true value and the percent error?

Comment: @user2763502 see those comments you have at the beginning of your code which tell you the "exact" formula for trapezoid area? Use those formulas to calculate the exact value. Then you just use the formula for percentage error which is `100*(math.fabs(Approximate Value - Exact Value)/math.fabs(Exact Value))` where `math.fabs` is the absolute value function.

Comment: @ShashankGupta do I define something else to be able to change the comments into actually computing the exact value?

Comment: @user2763502 well yes, you could define another function like `ExactTrapArea` to do the computation for you.

Comment: @ShashankGupta, so am I changing a and b in the equations to pi and 0 for the ExactTrapArea?

Comment: @ShashankGupta I defined ExactTrapArea, and then am I just putting the comment lines underneath that without making them comment lines?

Comment: @ShashankGupta I'm getting results from this TrapArea that seem to approach the value 1+(pi/n) instead of 2, which is the exact integral.

Answer (score 1):

A "nicer" way to do the trapezoid rule with equally-spaced points...

Let `dx = pi/n` be the width of the interval.  Also, let f(i) be sin(i*dx) to shorten some expressions below.  Then interval i (in `range(1,n)`) contributes:

```
dA = 0.5*dx*( f(i) + f(i-1) )
```

...to the sum (which is an area, so I'm using dA for "delta area").  Factoring out the 0.5*dx, makes the whole some look like:

```
A = 0.5*dx * ( (f(0) + f(1)) + (f(1) + f(2)) + .... + (f(n-1) + f(n)) )
```

Notice that there are two f(1) terms, two f(2) terms, on up to two f(n-1) terms.  Combine those to get:

```
A = 0.5*dx * ( f(0) + 2*f(1) + 2*f(2) + ... + 2*f(n-1) + f(n) )
```

The 0.5 and 2 factors cancel except in the first and last terms:

```
A = 0.5*dx(f(0) + f(n)) + dx*(f(1) + f(2) + ... + f(n-1))
```

Finally, you can factor dx out entirely to do just one multiplication at the end.  Converting back to sin() calls, then:

```
def TrapArea(n):
    dx = pi/n
    asum = 0.5*(sin(0) + sin(pi))   # this is 0 for this problem, but not others
    for i in range(1, n-1):
        asum += sin(i*dx)
    return sum*dx
```

That changed "sum" to "asum", or maybe "area" would be better.  That's mostly because sum() is a built-in function, which I'll use below the line.

---

Extra credit:  The loop part of the sum can be done in one step with a generator expression and the sum builtin function:

```
def TrapArea2(n):
    dx = pi/n
    asum = 0.5*(sin(0) + sin(pi))
    asum += sum(sin(i*dx) for i in range(1,n-1))
    return asum*dx
```

Testing both of those:

```
>>> for n in [1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000]:
        print n, TrapArea(n), TrapArea2(n)

1 1.92367069372e-16 1.92367069372e-16
10 1.88644298557 1.88644298557
100 1.99884870579 1.99884870579
1000 1.99998848548 1.99998848548
10000 1.99999988485 1.99999988485
```

That first line is a "numerical zero", since math.sin(math.pi) evaluates to about 1.2e-16 instead of exactly zero.  Draw the single interval from 0 to pi and the endpoints are indeed both 0 (or nearly so.)